# Android Bluetooth connection with OBD port

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm doing an application that comunicate with car by an OBD 2 port.
Now i'm working with bluetooth connection and i'm reading Android documentation and have some issues about connection and comunication with obd device.

I'm moving like this steps:
1)If bluetooth not active, activate the bluetooth
2)search device and show in a list
3)OnItemClick in the listview for connect with touched device (founded) with a client bluetooth connection

And here i have some problem to understand the Android documentation....

For the connection with device i use this code (like documentation)

```
foundedDeviceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                                    final int position, long id) {

                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                String deviceName = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selezionato: " + deviceName,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                for(BluetoothDevice dv : deviceList){
                    if(dv.getName() != null && dv.getName().equals(deviceName)){
                        selectedDevice = dv;
                    }
                }

                ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
                connectThread.run();


            }
        });

   //Thread of bluetooth connection
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket
            // because mmSocket is final.
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;

            try {
                // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice.
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used in the server code.
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                Log.i(TAG, "Socket's create() successfull");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket's create() method failed", e);
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }



        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it otherwise slows down the connection.
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.i(TAG, "run() eseguito");

            try {
                // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and return.
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", closeException);
                }
                return;
            }

            // The connection attempt succeeded. Perform work associated with
            // the connection in a separate thread.
            //manageMyConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
        }

        // Closes the client socket and causes the thread to finish.
        public void cancel() {
            Log.i(TAG, "cancel() eseguito");
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure about the `connectThread.run()` they don't explain the usage of method inside ConnectThread and i don't know how declare the `manageMyConnectedSocket(mmSocket);`

For the comunication i create a class MyBluetoothService.java and like documentation i write this code:

```
package com.tesi.ddz.obd_project;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Created by ddz on 24/04/17.
 */

public class MyBluetoothService{

    private static final String TAG = "MY_APP_DEBUG_TAG";
    private Handler mHandler; // handler that gets info from Bluetooth service

    // Defines several constants used when transmitting messages between the
    // service and the UI.
    private interface MessageConstants {
        public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0;
        public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 1;
        public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 2;

        // ... (Add other message types here as needed.)
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private byte[] mmBuffer; // mmBuffer store for the stream

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams; using temp objects because
            // member streams are final.
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
            }
            try {
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating output stream", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream.
                    numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                    Message readMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                            MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1,
                            mmBuffer);
                    readMsg.sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device.
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);

                // Share the sent message with the UI activity.
                Message writtenMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                        MessageConstants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, mmBuffer);
                writtenMsg.sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data", e);

                // Send a failure message back to the activity.
                Message writeErrorMsg =
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(MessageConstants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("toast",
                        "Couldn't send data to the other device");
                writeErrorMsg.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(writeErrorMsg);
            }
        }

        // Call this method from the main activity to shut down the connection.
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the connect socket", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would implement the method `manageMyConnectedSocket(mmSocket);` by calling the class `MyBluetoothService.java` and manage the connection as i understand the documentation....

They declare ConnectedThread as private so i can't call this method in the MainActivity.java.... so what is the best way to implement this connection?
Don't use MyBluetoothService and declare all to the MainActivity or keep working like that and maybe declare ConnectedThred public so i can use it in the MainActivity?

Especially i don't understand how use the class `MyBluetoothService.java` and the method `manageMyConnectionSocket(mmsocket)`